# Repeated pattern in case conditions without hard coding (Netezza SQL)

Tags: sql, netezza

Is there a better way to create case expression without hard coding it?

Eg.

```
            SELECT
                CASE
                        WHEN PRICE BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN '$1~$10'
                        WHEN PRICE BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '$11~$20'
                        WHEN PRICE BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '$21~$30'
                        WHEN PRICE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '$31~$40'
                        WHEN PRICE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '$41~$50'
                END AS PRICE_RANGE,
                SUM(TRANSACTION_COUNT),
                SUM(TRANSACTION_AMT)
            FROM SALES 
            WHERE
                CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 1 AND 10
                OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 11 AND 20
                OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 21 AND 30
                OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 31 AND 40
                OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 41 AND 50
           GROUP BY 1;
```

I am trying to categorize products with prices based on a range of price as shown above. I need to categorize from $1-$500 in denominations of 10.

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement. (It returns a value!)

Comment: Something like divide by 10, floor / ceiling, multiply again.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query as follow:

your output will be: price - mod(price, 10)

```
SELECT
    price - mod(price, 10) as 'Min limit',
    price + 10 - mod(price, 10) as 'Max limit' ... and so on
```

You can convert the output of SELECT in a string with your pattern. But I've focalized on maths expression to reduce your code line.

So, in this way you can remove the `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

I am not generating the series from $1 to $500

But I am creating one at run time.

Assuming you are using `SQL SERVER`

```
SELECT '$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),PRICE/10*10+1)+'~$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),(PRICE/10+1)*10)
```

Comment: the OP uses Netezza, no Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT '$' + CAST((@price / 10) * 10 + 1 AS varchar) + '~$' + CAST((@price / 10) * 10 + 10 AS varchar) AS PRICE_RANGE
      ,SUM(TRANSACTION_AMT)
FROM SALES 
WHERE CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 1 AND 10
OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 11 AND 20
OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 21 AND 30
OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 31 AND 40
OR CLR.DW_NET_PD_AMT BETWEEN 41 AND 50
GROUP BY 1;
```